# Mystery of a small 1K hard disk partition, and is it safe or malware on Ubuntu 12.04.02LTS Amd64 generic

Tags: ubuntu, partition

Look at my bizarre sda4 partition.  It is just 1K in size! Be mindful that this is not cluster size, this is partition size. I did not knowingly install this sda4 super small partition.  This is not my boot partition, it's some other thing.  I can't seem to find anyone else with the same tiny partition.

For what reason did this small sda4 partition get created?  Is it safe or malware?

This is a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04.02LTS for Amd64. The computer has just one physical hard disk and one DVD device at this time. This is not a multiboot computer at this time, only one OS at this time.

Here is the output from program lsblk:

```
ga@moonentity:~$ lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0  48.8G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0   5.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   9.3G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Yes I have 400GB of unallocated space on purpose. It will be used for another OS eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the output of `fdisk -l` too. @eppesuig got it right, `/dev/sda4` is an *extended* partition to contain the *logical* `/dev/sda5 partition

On my system:

```
:) ✭ [~] $> sudo lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda3   8:3    0  39.1G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 422.7G  0 part /home
└─sda6   8:6    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

and

```
:) ✭ [~] $> sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe3102a4b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda3            2048    81919999    40958976   83  Linux
/dev/sda4        81920000   976771071   447425536    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        81922048   968302591   443190272   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       968304640   976771071     4233216   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

As you can see the `1K` `/dev/sda4` is really a "container" for the logical partitions `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6`, `fdisk` shows the "real" block occupation (447425536 blocks) which is the space occupied by `sda5` *and* `sda6` (plus some more, probably partition data).

Comment: Now it does look like sda4 (Extended) merely contains sda5.  I ran fdisk -l, as you suggested.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but Stackexchange refused it. I have also accepted your answer, which Stackexchange permitted.  Thanks to all for helping out!  Stackexchange is a little bit derpy sometimes.

Comment: @user36849 yes, in your case `/dev/sda4` contains only `sda5`. In my case `sda4` is *logical*, too.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because sda5 is a logical partition and maybe its does have different rounding offset than physical ones. Or Ubuntu installer may have created sda4 on purpose this size. I think you can really ignore it safely.

Comment: Agreed, now it does look like sda4 (Extended) merely contains sda5, and I think I can ignore it safely, as you suggested.  Thank you for replying.  I wish I could give more than one up vote.

Answer (score 0):

I ran sudo fdisk -l, as suggested by Mr. Shunz. I have accepted the answer by Mr. Shunz.

(BTW, Stackexchange would not permit me to format this information clearly using the Comment feature. Carriage returns which I attempted to insert merely posted the comment prematurely.  Therefore I used the Answer feature instead, so that others could read this information and understand it.)

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1   *        2048      616447      307200   83  Linux

/dev/sda2          616448   103016447    51200000   8e  Linux LVM

/dev/sda3       103016448   115304447     6144000   82  Linux swap / Solaris

/dev/sda4       115306494   134836223     9764865    5  Extended

/dev/sda5       115306496   134836223     9764864   83  Linux